# Quandl is not being imported

Tags: python, quandl

I'm getting started for Machine learning using Python and would like to use Quandl for computing. I installed the Quandl using `pip install Quandl` and also, pandas using `pip install pandas`. Later, the `import` for pandas is successful, but, I couldn't import quandl. I get error as following,

```
`ImportError: No module named Quandl`
```

I use Python 2.7 and Quandl supports both 2 and 3 version of Python. How to do the import properly ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at [the docs](https://www.quandl.com/tools/python), it is lower case:

```
import quandl
```